# Why can't I import QGIS module in PyCharm

Tags: qgis, python, conda

I have used the following command-line successfully (python3.7)

> conda install -c conda-forge qgis

and I'm able to import the `qgis-python` module by `import qgis` in IPython.

However, when I tried to import qgis-python module in PyCharm (I am quite sure in the same conda environment as the environment mentioned before), I was warned

> no module named qgis

Is there anything I need to do before If I want to import qgis package in PyCharm of VSCode? Or It is not allowed to import it outside QGIS?

[image: successfully imported in ipython]

[image: successfully installed (conda list command)]

[image: failed in PyCharm]

Comment: Actually I need to use python module from conda rather than qgis-python installed with QGIS3.17 because we need to develop something without QGIS Desktop

Comment: Not sure about conda, but if you installed QGIS with OSGeo4W - check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337623/35561

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm does not seem to actually *activate* the environment which means that QGIS' Python paths are not registered.

Check these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath/72996502#72996502
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924787/pycharm-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment/51180357#51180357
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000498/properly-activating-conda-environments-in-pycharm