# RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am writing a standalone script in atom to create a new project and load a layer. The problem is that I wanna use the next command:

`vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer('', '', '')`

To load layers, then, I first need to import iface from qgis.utils. But, when I run my script in cmd, I get the following error:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\qgis\python\qgis\utils.py", line 34, in <module>
    from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\qgis\python\qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._gui import *
RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore
```

I set the path as we can see

[image]

and create de PYTHONPATH

[image]

I have installed PyQt5 through pip as well. I am out of ideas, can someone please help me?

My code, if it can be of help is:

```
import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

#supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis", True)
#create a reference to the QgsApplication. setting the second argument to
#False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
#load providers
qgs.initQgis()
#get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()

#add vector layer
layerPath = r"C:\Users\alvaro.garcia.daroca\OneDrive - Accenture\Documents\Qgis - Daroca\Telefónica - pruebas\Daun\KREIS - DAUN_ORTS.gpkg"
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(layerPath, 'Orts', 'ogr')
if not vlayer:
    print('Layer failed to load!')

project.write('prueba.qgs')
print('\n END')
qgs.exitQgis()
```

I have in my computer QGIS-3.22; Python-3.9; Windows 10.

Comment: It's not advised to install PyQt5 from pip for a PyQGIS use since QGIS comes already with a specific PyQt version and this can be the conflict.

Comment: I have read about that, but when I uninstalled PyQt5 (pip uninstall PyQt5), and run the script again, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'), then, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Try to set a `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH`, see here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337623/93097, not an OSGEO one for you, but set a path from progam files.

Comment: I tried to set a QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH as you told me, but the error is still there. To be sure, I went into path variables in windows and I created new system variable as: QT_QPA_PLAT...=C:Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms.

Comment: First : try your code under the QGIS Python console, if it works ok. Next step is too look a `.bat` file under QGIS directory (bin ?) that sets the environment variables before launch the QGIS app, so you have "just" to copy the env variables.

Comment: I ran my code and it works well in QGIS Python Console. Now I am looking for a .bat file in QGIS directory in the bin subfolder. But there are several .bat files, I suppose I had to choose python-qgis.bat. I copied: QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\apps\qgis\python. But nothing has changed.

Comment: Look at `qgis-bin.env`, `qt5_env.bat` and `py3_env.bat`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131136/discussion-between-alvaro-garcia-daroca-and-j-monticolo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments above, I found an answer.

Since I installed PyQt5 with pip, I decided to uninstall by typing in my cmd:

*pip uninstall PyQt5*

Then the error changed to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'

Then, I went to -> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.0\bin. There I opened qgis-bin.env with a plain text editor, and I copied all the enviroment variables that are underlined,

[image]

into my enviroment variables as system variables.

[image]

Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while writing tests for a QGIS Plugin. I used the accepted answer, and it worked for me. Furthermore, I was able to narrow down the exact environmental variable from the list that caused this error, and it was the `PYTHONHOME`. So I had to `SET` it before running the `unittest` command.

Here is how my `.bat` file looks like:

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.1\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39

python -m unittest
```