# PyQGIS outside GUI: module 'qgis.processing' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, standalone

When trying to use `processing.run()` from a standalone (no GUI) mode, I get the following error:

```
module 'qgis.processing' has no attribute 'run'
```

in the following trivial example:

```py
from qgis import processing
result = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT': 'test', 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})
```

Other methods, like `algorithmHelp()`, don't seem to work either.

I followed the Windows setup instructions from here:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications

Setting the following environment vars:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python
```

and `PATH` is appended with `C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin`

Anything I'm missing here?

NOTE: When running the same script from inside the GUI (using the Script editor), all goes well and I don't get these errors. Somehow the environment seems to be different between the two.

QGIS version is 3.22.2-Białowieża.

Comment: I'm really not an expert on this, but I was recently experiencing a similar error when using a script in the layer action context, that I had been working with for some time in the script editor where I didn't get that kind of error. 
What worked for me was to ensure the 'from qgis import processing' was the very first line of the script. But the if your trivial example still comes up with the same error, I guess that that solution is no help in your case unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I got the same error :(

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis-3-processing-algorithms-from-pyqgis-standalone-scripts-outside-of-gu

Comment: @BenW thanks! I actually tried that earlier today, but got this weird error below. And since that answer was posted 3 years ago, I figured this setup probably changed. Any thoughts? qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._gui import *
  File "processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 38, in <module>
    from qgis.gui import QgsSublayersDialog
...<module>
    from processing.tools.dataobjects import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\svn\qgis\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    import processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is posted here:

[Looking for manual on how to properly setup standalone PyQGIS without GUI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421362/looking-for-manual-on-how-to-properly-setup-standalone-pyqgis-without-gui)

At the time of writing I didn't know the two were related. But I found a workable solution in that post. Thanks all for your answers here!

Answer (score 5):

You also need to add the following lines:

```py
# To import section
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

...
...

# after qgs.initQgis() 
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

...
...
```

Sometimes developing a PyQGIS standalone application can be tiring. Especially for those new to this topic. You need to open your editor using a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT="C:\OSGeo4W"
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts
set QGIS_PREFIX=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;%PYTHONPATH%
set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT\apps\qt5\plugins

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000

start "Visual Studio QGIS" /B "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
```

---

A working example here: (change `source_path`).

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

import processing
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from processing.core.Processing import Processing


### GUI Construction ###
class MapViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)

        self._canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self._root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self._root, self._canvas)
        self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self._root)
        self.model.setFlag(0x25043)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
        self.layer_treeview = QgsLayerTreeView()
        self.layer_treeview.setModel(self.model)

        self.layer_tree_dock = QDockWidget("Layers")
        self.layer_tree_dock.setObjectName("layers")
        self.layer_tree_dock.setFeatures(QDockWidget.NoDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.layer_tree_dock.setWidget(self.layer_treeview)

        self.splitter = QSplitter()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.layer_tree_dock)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self._canvas)
        self.splitter.setCollapsible(0, False)
        self.splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 1)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.contents = QWidget()
        self.contents.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.contents)

        self.load_layers()

    def load_layers(self):
        source_path = "path/to/data/source"
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(source_path, 'Layer1', 'ogr')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self._canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self._canvas.setLayers([layer])

        ### PROCESSING
        result = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT': source_path, 'DISTANCE':10, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result["OUTPUT"])
########################
        
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

main_window = MapViewer()
main_window.show()

qgs.exec_()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where did you get this information from? It's not in the official docs about writing external scripts, as that simply mentioned `from qgis import processing` and that's it. Your example unfortunately gave me the following error: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'processing'
  File "C:\svn\qgis\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Comment: Haha yes it definitely is missing. It's mostly trial and error and looking up articles here, than that I could use the official documentation. When I try to run your example `as is`, I get a very weird error: Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._gui import *
  File "C:\svn\qgis\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from qgis.gui import *

Comment: How do you open IDE? Do you use VS Code?

Comment: I test this code in VS Code indeed.

Comment: I use VS Code, too. I open it using a batch file, which contains settings for some environment variables. And the example runs seamlessly.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share (parts of) that .bat file with me?

Comment: I have added the related batch file content I use.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this still gives me the: `qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore` error. I'll try a reinstall :(

Comment: Turns out to be a conflicting PyQT install. So I removed that. But then I got into the problem that PyQt couldn't be found. So I took the batch file from here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337558/import-qgis-core-in-pycharm-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtcore/337623#337623 which got me a bit further, now processing errored with `No module named 'osgeo'`. It's really incredible how frustratingly difficult this is, especially with no official docs on it

Comment: I found a solution that works and created a GitHub repo for it https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone perhaps you may find it useful. Thanks a lot for all the answers!